# How can I use 'edit_form_after_title' conditionally?

Tags: conditional-content

I'm using it to add a message to posts/pages/cpts, but it's also appearing on one screen of a plugin - so I need to remove it.

I have the screenID, but my knowledge-lacking efforts to add a conditional between the opening brace and echo in the code below produce a variety of errors.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function( $post ) {
echo "<div class=\"add-message\">
<p>Message.</p>
</div><!-- /add-message -->";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it might be worth restricting your message specifically to the screens you want the message to appear on, rather than having it appear everywhere except a plugin page. The screen ids of "post" and "page" are self-explanatory; just add more "or" clauses with the double pipes and include any custom post types you want the message to appear on.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function( $post ) {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if($screen->id == 'post' || $screen->id == 'page' || $screen->id == 'your_cpt_slug') {
echo "<div class=\"add-message\">
<p>Message.</p>
</div><!-- /add-message -->";
}
});
```

If instead you do want it to appear everywhere in the admin except your particular plugin screen ID, substitute that screen ID for 'screen_to_hide_on' below:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function( $post ) {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if($screen->id != 'screen_to_hide_on') {
echo "<div class=\"add-message\">
<p>Message.</p>
</div><!-- /add-message -->";
}
});
```

Comment: @ WebElaine... thanks. Excellent. You've helped me to understand something which had befuddled me.